# Error in export image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to export the image from the Google Earth Engine. However, it had
Error: Export region contains no valid (un-masked) pixels. How to fix this error? This is the link of my google earth engine code: 
  https://code.earthengine.google.com/707b7d4b84a0e14f0db74b38533666e6.
The code is as follow:

```js
    // Load a Fusion Table of state boundaries and filter.
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw')
    .filterMetadata('Country','equals','New Zealand');
// Load Landsat 8 imagery and filter it  
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterBounds(fc).set('SENSOR_ID', 'OLI_TIRS');
var filtered = collection
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 10);
// Function to cloud mask from the Fmask band of Landsat 8 SR data.
function maskL8sr(image) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).float();
}
// Map the function .
var filtered_1 = filtered.map(maskL8sr);
function a(image) {
  var equation = image.expression(
    '(7.27 * B4/B3) - 1.7',
    {
        B3: image.select('B4'),    
        B4: image.select('B3'),   
    }).rename('NEW_A').float();
  return image.addBands(equation);
}
var b = filtered_1.map(a).median();
print (b,'NEW_B');
// Display the results.
var vizParams = {bands: ['NEW_A'], min: 0, max: 100};
Map.addLayer(b, vizParams, 'recent value composite');
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: b,
  description: 'NEW_B',
  scale: 30,
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

All credit for this update goes for @NicholasClinton, who wisely guided me (us) to the correct answer.

The error is due to argument `region` for function `Export.image.toDrive`. It can be set when calling the function, otherwise it defaults to *the viewport at the time of invocation* as the documentation clearly specifies. So there are 2 solutions.

1. Setting parameter `region`:

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: b,
  description: 'NEW_B',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels:1e13,
  region: ee.Feature(fc.first()).geometry().bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']
});
```

2. setting the viewport at the time of exporting

```js
Map.centerObject(fc, 9)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: b,
  description: 'NEW_B',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels:1e13
});
```

and `maxPixels=1e13` because image is too big.

Comment: The issue is not the unboundedness.  It's the fact that `Export.image.toDrive()` defaults to the Code Editor viewport.  The `ImageCollection` is filtered to a bounds that is not in the same place as specified in the `Map.setCenter()` call.  Therefore, there are no unmasked pixels in the export.  One solution is to set a suitable region in the export as shown, however, the `Map.setCenter()` call should be replaced by `Map.centerObject(fc, 9)`.

Comment: Thank you @NicholasClinton!! You are totally right. I updated the answer to match your comment.